# How to add keypress events in event queue for pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I have a game made with pygame which runs perfectly okay. I want to create a system which reads keys to press from a file (which will contain codes of keys to press in separate lines) and adds them to the pygame event queue so that the player agent moves on its own without the keys actually being pressed.

After reading the pygame docs I have tried to create a new event object and add it to the queue but the event constructor requires attributes which I could not find anywhere.

Does anyone know which attributes are needed to create an instance of an event or if there is another better approach for what I am trying to do?

**UPDATE:** I have successfully added my events to the queue however they do not seem to work even though they are completely identical to the ones created automatically. I am printing the event queue below. Highlighted events are added when I actually press the 'a' key. As you can see my events (the ones above) do not trigger the rest of the events as they should.
[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I added some print statements to the event handling code for the keydown events. These are only executed if I actually press the key on the keyboard and just seem to ignore the events I raise from the code.
       `input_list = [pg.K_RETURN, pg.K_a, pg.K_s]
        if self.cursor.state == c.PLAYER1:
            self.cursor.rect.y = 358
            if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
                print("down")
                self.cursor.state = c.PLAYER2
            for input in input_list:
                if keys[input]:
                    print("button")
                    self.reset_game_info()
                    self.done = True
        elif self.cursor.state == c.PLAYER2:
            self.cursor.rect.y = 403
            if keys[pg.K_UP]:
                print("up")
                self.cursor.state = c.PLAYER1`

I am creating my events like so:
`pg.event.post(pg.event.Event(pg.KEYDOWN, {'mod': 0, 'scancode': 30, 'key': pg.K_a, 'unicode': 'a'}))`
I found these values by printing the event which happens when I actually press the key 'a'.

Comment: Although this isn't what you asked for, maybe it'd be better to queue these actions higher level in your game. For example if keypresses are changing the player's momentum and you want to automate movement you could change the momentum directly instead of queueing up key events.

Comment: You've confused events with state; that's why it doesn't work. I don't see where you define `keys` but I'm guessing your doing `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`. This will return the states of all keys and *not* the events.

Comment: You guessed correct. When I press a key it changes the respective value in the keys tuple but my event doesn't do that. I want that behavior to happen due to my code.

Comment: Because the events are put in the event queue while `pygame.key.get_pressed()` is returning the states of every key. Your event is not a key and cannot trigger any key, hence will never affect the state of any key. When using your own events you need to post it manually and then iterate through the event queue and find it and handle it. Keypresses are events but the state of the key is not; events are handled by iterating through the event queue (like I showed in my examples). Doing it the way you're currently doing isn't not going to work with events.

Comment: Here's the Stackoverflow documentation on state checking and event loop: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling#t=201609251634055510405

Comment: So I can not effectively create a fake keypress event however I can create another event which triggers the same code as a keypress event?

Answer (score 0):

The [Event object's](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) first argument is its type, which is an integer between `pygame.USEREVENT` and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (24 to 32 exclusive). This is used to identify your event from other events, such as `pygame.KEYDOWN`, `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` etc.

The second argument is either a dictionary or keyword arguments. These will be your event's attributes. The dict should contain strings as keys.

Here's a short example demonstrating how it's used:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

event1 = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {"greeted": False, "jumped": 10, "ID": 1})
event2 = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, greeted=True, jumped=200, ID=2)

pygame.event.post(event1)
pygame.event.post(event2)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        raise SystemExit
    elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        print("Player:", event.ID, "| Greeted:", event.greeted, "| Jumped:", event.jumped)
    elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1:
        print("Player:", event.ID, "| Greeted:", event.greeted, "| Jumped:", event.jumped)
```

This will output:

```
Player: 1 | Greeted: False | Jumped: 10
Player: 2 | Greeted: True | Jumped: 200
```

Comment: `The second argument is either a dictionary or keyword arguments. `

I need this dictionary for a keypress event so if I add my custom event right after my game loads (let's say for right arrow) the character moves towards right as soon as he loads.
What would be the values in this dictionary?

Comment: Anything you want. These events will just be added in the event loop; you'll need to do the checking and handling yourself. Let's say you start by posting an event with an attribute move, then you need to check for that event and what it's move attribute is. Like [this](http://hastebin.com/omatucobir.cs) for example.

Comment: I have added my own keypress events to the events queue. They are completely identical to the ones that are added automatically however my events do not trigger the code which a manual keypress does.

Comment: @RabeezRiaz It should. Are you posting the events manually? Are your events of the same type that you're checking (in the event loop)? Are you checking it's type *and then* the attribute? If yes for these questions, could you put your code in the question (edit in the code) or use something like http://hastebin.com/ so I can look at it?

Comment: [Here's a short example how you could create an event of the same type as a keypress.](http://hastebin.com/wikohobedu.cs)

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. If I raise a pygame.QUIT event the game closes (as it should because this event is handled) however the pygame.KEYDOWN events do not trigger anything.

Comment: Could you give a short example of your code? It's hard to figure out what's wrong because it should work the way I've demonstrated.